# NodeJS and npm without sudo on CentOS

Tags: linux, node.js, permissions, npm

On my box I have the Node and NPM binaries installed under /opt/node/bin. And the path is added properly.

```
node -v
```

and

```
npm -v
```

work fine. When I create a file and run it with node all works as expected. However, when I run:

```
npm init
```

the program fails to write package.json because it does not have write permission. I use:

```
sudo npm init
```

I get a file with owner and group of 0 0 and so any regular users cannot modify this file. I don't want to have to chown every file node/npm generates.

Is there way to get node/npm to run as a user in the same group as my other users and have write permissions to the same directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply `chown` your `/opt/` directory and future calls to `npm init` will be owned by you. Better yet, work in your `/home` folder and make sure npm and node are in your `$PATH`. This way you don't need to worry about permissions for initializing a new node module. You will, however, need to use `sudo` to install packages globally. This is bad practice according to the maintainer of Nodejs:

http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm

I would follow along with his setup there. As he mentions, its very dangerous to give root access to a package manager.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and worked great. Many thanks.